# Can I prove this axiom without using excluded-middle property?

Tags: coq

I define the following axiom.

(First, I want to prove it, and make it Theorem.
However, I can not find how to start.)

```
Axiom functions_eq_or_not :
forall f g : (Q -> bool), 
(forall q : Q, f q = g q) \/ (exists q : Q, f q <> g q).
```

Can I prove it (without using excluded middle) and make it Theorem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `Q` is `nat` your principle is equivalent to [LPO](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+omniscience#the_limited_principle_of_omniscience), which is not provable in intuitionistic logic.

[Martín Escardó](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/) extensively studied for which `Q` the principle holds, see for example [Exhaustible sets in higher-type computation](https://doi.org/10.2168/LMCS-4(3:3)2008) and [Infinite sets that admit fast exhaustive search](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/papers/exhaustive.pdf).